# Why is my phone app wallet showing true balance and my web wallet showing 0 balance

Tags: blockchain, wallet, balance

I downloaded my wallet app to my phone my online wallet shows 0 balance my phone app shows true balance why isnt my online wallet showing same balance as phone

Comment: Which wallet app are you using? It is hard to help without additional info.

Comment: My account Mgr setup the blockchain bit coin wallet online but only got me to download the blockchain app on my phone and never finished setting up the wallet online so app on my phone is showing a balance and the online wallet shows a zero balance, I can access the online wallet by entering my password and google authentication code and it takes me right through to the wallet ... I dont know how to fix this in order to move forward and get the coins out .... but first of all I need the both to be either synced or paired and I dont have the technical knowledge to get through this!

Comment: Are you talking about the blockchain.info wallet/app? Why are you unable to use the wallet app on your phone to transfer the coins? If the wallet contains funds, you should be able to spend them on the phone app, no need to log into the web-wallet. Who is your ‘account manager’, and why are they involved? Normally no such thing is needed.

Comment: I am a novice at all of this hence why I decided to go with a manager...however I have been left high and dry, your answer makes lots of sense. I have a buyer who is willing to buy the bitcoins for what I want, but thought I could only complete the transaction online..I have told the interested party what has happened...I guess what you have suggested is worth a try. So I would get an address off the buyer and send the bitcoins via their address I just dont know the steps to take Would you be able to assist in the steps to take.... .My Account Manager is James Patrick from kryptosmart247....

Comment: YES chytrik it is the blockchain app downloaded from the play store. What worries me is the online wallet is showing a zero balance he told me he would go in and put it right today....I had to send him a fee of 1300.00 in order for him to proceed...he hasnt been back in touch since...I am totally shattered as Im out of funds, and being ignorant just dont know what to do....

Comment: Unfortunately it sounds like you were scammed, there is no reason to send $1300 to an 'account manager' in normal circumstances. To send bitcoins: Get a bitcoin address from the buyer. Open your wallet app and go to the 'send' section. Paste the bitcoin address in the 'pay to' field, set fees according to the app's recommendation, and then send. Importantly: **MAKE SURE you can trust the buyer will pay you! Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed, it is advised trade using a reputable exchange, or someone you trust completely**.

Comment: For general 'getting started' info for bitcoin, check out this Q: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started.

Comment: Chytrik thanks for your help would like to add you on messenger if you agree You can find me on FB I will let you take the lead on this one ....FB name Flo Tupaea

Comment: I do not use messenger/facebook, beware anyone contacting you and claiming to be me outside of this website. If you'd like to contact me please do so through this website, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

> **I had to send him a fee of 1300.00 in order for him to proceed...he hasnt been back in touch since.**

You are the victim of a scam.

> **My account Mgr ... got me to download the blockchain app on my phone**

I suspect he may have got you to import an address also.

Can you tell whether the app on your phone has a "watch-only" address? If so, your crooked "account manager" will probably tell you to pay him some large sum for a private-key. If so, this also is typical of a scam.

> **My Account Manager is James Patrick from kryptosmart247**

The domain name kryptosmart247.com was only registered a month ago using NameCheap. Inc. Their webpage contains spelling mistakes like "Mointor Your Trade". Their website looks exactly like that of 24cryptostar.com. Same "Seth Trevor" etc photographs. I suspect one or both websites are just quickly set up copies of something generic.

In other words, to me this does not look trustworthy.

> **You can find me on FB I will let you take the lead on this one**

Unfortunately, this is the kind of thinking that lost you your money. You don't need to trust random strangers who approach you on the Internet. I expect chytrik is a decent person but you just advertised to any crooks reading this that they can get money out of you by impersonating him.

---

I think you should report your kryptosmart247 experience to the police but should not expect to get any of your money back.

---

See

- [How can I safely store and trade Bitcoin and other crypto currencies?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75099/13866)
- [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22796/13866)
- [Getting started with Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.org/en/getting-started)

Comment: *"I expect chytrik is a decent person but you just advertised to any crooks reading this that they can get money out of you by impersonating him. "* A very good point! Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your online wallet is working correctly, you need to make sure that both wallets display the same bitcoin address.

Many people get the concept of a crypto wallet wrong. Technically, you wallet does not "store" anything, it's not a container for your coins. You should think of it rather as a viewing tool which displays what the blockchain has recorded as "your" balance.

Comment: Block explorers are more akin to 'viewing tools'. Wallets are perhaps most analogous to keychain apps, as the store the keys which allow you to spend your coins.

Comment: Yes, kind of both, actually. I was trying to get the point across, that the wallet does not actually *contain* your coins, but you're right, the keychain function is possibly the more important one.